# Upload Image row wise in a grid column with upload Button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I have a requirement of uploading the photo of members also displaying it before upload  in a grid column. Each row will have different photo for uploading. I have added the image column inside the item template of grid column. I am using the File reader for uploading the photo to the grid but every time i upload it to the next row of grid it is replacing the first row uploaded image. I want to upload it row wise.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload Photo">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 11px"><div style="vertical-align: top; padding-left: 11px" id="ImageHolderAddEnrollee"> <img alt="Upload your photo" src="/images/DefaultView.gif" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /> </div>
         <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="EnrolleeFileUpload" CssClass="file-upload-button" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The `jQuery` code for preview and upload photo -

```
$('#<%=grdEnorlleeAdditionalInfo.ClientID %>').find('input:file[id$="EnrolleeFileUpload"]').on('change', function () {
  var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
  var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
  var image_holder = $("#ImageHolderAddEnrollee");
  image_holder.empty();
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
              $("<img />", {
                  "src": e.target.result                                      
              }).appendTo(image_holder);
          }
          image_holder.show();
          reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of requirement we can make use of user control inside the grid column as following :

Code from User control .ascx file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UploadPhoto.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.UserControls.WebUserControl1" %>
```

And add the Preview code of File Reader to this .ascx page to the  tag.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblImage" runat="server"><img id="DefaultImage" src="images/DefaultView.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px;"/>
</asp:Label><asp:FileUpload id="ImageUpload" runat="server" />




<script  type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=ImageUpload.ClientID%>').on('change', function () 
            {
                var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
                var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
                var image_holder = $("#<%=lblImage.ClientID%>");{
                           image_holder.empty();
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                $("<img />", {
                                    "src": e.target.result,
                                    "ID": "DefaultImage"
                                }).appendTo(image_holder);
                            }
                            image_holder.show();
                            reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                        }
                });
        });

</script>
```

Once done add the reference of your user control page to your parent page where you want to add you grid column & simply add the user control of file upload into Item Template of grid column.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload Photo">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <uc:ImageUpload id="ImageUpload" runat="server" />

                                                </ItemTemplate>

                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

This will allow to upload photo to each row of grid with different user control  of file upload.